# How to show the information I get from the user in a pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show the information I get from the user in pages with prev and next button, not on one page
I like to show every 5 elements on one page

```
const incomeItemShow = incomeContent.map(value => <SummaryItem key= 
{value.id} money={value} func={props.money} />);
```

incomeContent is an Array and hold data i get from user Including an object `{id: 0, check: "in", number: "12000", text: "sometext"}`

Comment: So essentially you want pagination. I don't see any pagination related code in your question. What have you tried? P.s. for this you might want to consider some npm/yarn package for react that does pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you tried so far?
If it would be me, at first glance I would create a property in the state, something like `currentItemDisplayed`, which is an array of two numbers. The first element is the index of the first element of `incomeContent`that is displayed, while the second element is the index of the last element of `incomeContent` that is displayed.

Then, you display the two buttons, which will have `onClick={this.back}` and `onClick={this.forward}`, where these two functions could be something like:

```
back = () => {
  const currentItemDisplayed = Object.assign([], this.state.currentItemDisplayed);
  currentItemDisplayed[0] -= 5;
  currentItemDisplayed[1] -= 5;

  this.setState({currentItemDisplayed[0]});
}

forward = () => {
  const currentItemDisplayed = Object.assign([], this.state.currentItemDisplayed);
  currentItemDisplayed[0] += 5;
  currentItemDisplayed[1] += 5;

  this.setState({currentItemDisplayed[0]});
}
```

Be aware: you should cover the cases in which you are already displaying the first five elements and you click on the Back button. In that case, `back()` should not save `[-5, 0]` in the state, otherwise you will have error.

Finally, in the `render()` method you should write something like:

```
render() {
  const currentItemDisplayed = this.state.currentItemDisplayed;
  const itemToDisplay = incomeContent.slice(currentItemDisplayed[0], currentItemDisplayed[1]);

  ..

  return (
    ..
    {itemToDisplay.map(item => <SummaryItem ... /> )}
    ..
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to use an internal `index` to show the next items. It could look like this

```
const itemsToShow = incomeContent.slice(index, index + 5);
```

The buttons `prev` and `next` would increment/decrement the index by 5 or X. You might want to look into pagination which explains the concept of it.